# Read file and separate lowercase and uppercase to two different files (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

how to do I read a file, replace certain letters and write the replaced letters to a file in python?

Thanks in advance.

This is how far I got

```
> def mutate():
>     f=open("DNA.txt", "r")
>     onef= open("normalDNA.txt","w+")
>     twof= open("mutatedDNA.txt","w+")
> 
>     if f.mode == 'r':
>     for line in f.readlines():
>         .replace()
```

the DNA.txt file is the read file and contains

ACATTTGCTTCTGACACAACTGTGTTCACTAGCAACCTCAAACAGACACCATGGTGCATCTGACTCCTGa

The 'a' should be replaced with 'A' and printed to normalDNA.txt

then 'a' should be replaced again wtih 'T' and saved to another file mutatedDNA.txt

Comment: What specific letters are you looking to replace, and with what other letters?

Comment: Could you also share a sample of the data inside the file 'DNA.txt' and explain what you wish to achieve as output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's simply 'a' you want to replace, you might try (in your for loop):

```
onef.write(line.replace('a', 'A'))
twof.write(line.replace('a', 'T'))
```

Remember to close your files when you're finished with them (or, even better, open them as a context manager in the first place)